# Hiding divs other than targeted div on slideToggle

Tags: jquery

Sorry for the wording in the title but I wasn't sure how to exactly explain what is going on here. I have the following code here that basically expands the tbody element of a particular table which contains buttons that show other divs directly below the table. When the user presses "Close", I want it to also close any divs that may be open beneath the table that may have been opened via the links within the tbody. Heres my code:

```
$( "#pdays_expand" ).on( "click", function() {
               $( "#pdays_tbody" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
                    //$('body').scrollTo($('#pdays_tbody'),500);
                    $("#pdays_expand").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Close" : "Expand");
               });
               if (("#pdays_tbody").is(':hidden')) {
                    $( "#search_pdays_medicare" ).hide();
                    $( "#search_pdays_medicaid" ).hide();
                    $( "#search_pdays_other" ).hide();
                    $( "#search_pdays_totalallpay" ).hide();
                    $( "#search_pdays_totalcombine" ).hide();
                    }
            });
```

My issue is that when I press "Close" after the tbody has been toggled open. It does not close any of the #search divs listed below, they remain open beneath the table. The pdays_tbody div however, successfully closes.

Thanks

Comment: Can we have a fiddle or some HTML please?

Comment: http://hospitaldatasolutions.com/php/hosp_core.php Heres a link to the page where it is occurring, I had to turn off my security so it took me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is, you are checking to see if paydays_tbody is hidden before the slide animation has an opportunity to complete. Technically, it isn't hidden until the animation completes. Try moving the if block inside your complete callback and it should work:

```
$( "#pdays_expand" ).on( "click", function() {
  $( "#pdays_tbody" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    //$('body').scrollTo($('#pdays_tbody'),500);
    $("#pdays_expand").text($(this).is(':visible') ? "Close" : "Expand");

    if (("#pdays_tbody").is(':hidden')) {
      $( "#search_pdays_medicare" ).hide();
      $( "#search_pdays_medicaid" ).hide();
      $( "#search_pdays_other" ).hide();
      $( "#search_pdays_totalallpay" ).hide();
      $( "#search_pdays_totalcombine" ).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Also, consider using a common selector for the search divs (class is probably ideal).  It'll save you on a few jQuery calls and make your code a lot more readable and maintainable (say, if you ever want to add another search field).

Hope this helps!